# Where is the code used to build the official Live CD images?

Tags: live-cd

There are [several](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch) [pages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) describing how to build Ubuntu live CD images.  Where is the code used to build the official live CD images?

To be more precise: I'm talking about the particular code (maybe it's a single script, I don't know) used by Canonical to build the official images, not the source code for the generic tools (like squashfs) that are used by that code.

I'm assuming here that such code exists, and is published!  Maybe somebody at Canonical sits down and does it by hand every time.

Note that I'm not looking for an alternative way to build live CD images here: rather, I want to look at the code that was used to build the official images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it's a project called [ubuntu-cdimage](https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage).  It does not appear to be available as a package from the official APT repository.

> The Ubuntu CD image software is used to produce daily builds 
>   and releases of Ubuntu and its derivatives. At present it
>   consists of a significantly-modified version of `debian-cd` and
>   some fairly extensive wrapper scripts.

The [blog post](http://swem.logdown.com/posts/763254) I linked on your [other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897926/remaster-customize-16-04-live-cd-image-and-make-usb-bootable) linked to a ReleaseTeam page on the wiki ([CDImageSetup](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ReleaseTeam/CDImageSetup)) that mentioned the ubuntu-cdimage suite.  The suite looks geared toward large-scale production (daily ISO builds, testing, etc) rather than individual builds like the `live-build` and `ubuntu-defaults-builder` packages.