# How does canonical create the bootable ISOs?

Tags: iso

I'd like to create a live cd locally from scratch and was wondering how canonical does this themselves? Is there tooling around?

I've already been able to build the linux kernels and initrds by downloading

```
apt-get source debian-installer
make build_netboot
```

But I'd like a complete ISO just like Canonical would distribute such as 14.04.5. in fact if canonical would've created a 14.04.6 I wouldve been helped, since the kernel I need actually is in 14.04, just not in the 14.04.5 iso

Comment: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/ and welcome to the rest of your life learning linux ;-)

Comment: Hmm I wonder why my google attempt did not show those questions/references. Thanks, definitely will be checking that out

Comment: I should've been more specific. The above is geared towards LiveCDs, whereas I am interested in the classical (debian-installer based) server iso. Altering an existing ISO is not really the way to go as I am in need of a newer kernel which is not provided by 14.04.5. Editing the kernel seems problematic with implicit dependencies like all the udeb modules, e.g., scsi-modules-4.4.0-34-generic-di_4.4.0-34.53_amd64.udeb

Comment: @user535733 you are right, I updated it. Hopefully it explains my goal somewhat better.

Comment: Fyi: https://askubuntu.com/q/898603

Comment: It does, I voted to close my own question as a duplicate.